# View takes too long to render my results

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a controller that basically returns a IOrderedQueriable object through return View(result);

The point is that by the time that the view tries to execute that query, it takes lot of time and it ends up on some timeout exceptions. I believe the reason is because the query that gets created under result is extremely complex. I was wondering if I can have some advice on how to improve my linq query.

This is my ugly and nasty query:

```
public ActionResult FileList(string productName, string projectName)
{
    var tagCount = (from l in db.FileDatas
        from t in db.ProcessedFiles.Where(x => l.FileId == x.FileId &&
            l.ProductId == x.ProductId &&
            l.ProjectId == x.ProjectId &&
            l.Product.Product1.Equals(productName))
            .GroupBy(t => new { .ProductId, t.ProjectId, t.FileId, l.ExtensionId })

    select new GroupedTagsRow
    {
        ProductName = l.Product.Product1,
        ProjectName = l.Project.Project1,
        FileName = l.File.File1,
        Occurrences = t.Sum(x => x.Occurrences)
    });

    var unprocessedTags = db.UnProcessedTags
        .Where(x => x.Product.Product1.Equals(productName) &&
            x.Project.Project1.Equals(projectName) &&
            x.TagId != 1);

    var listOfFiles = db.FileDatas
        .Where(x => x.Product.Product1.Equals(productName) &&
        x.Project.Project1.Equals(projectName));

    var result = listOfFiles
        .GroupBy(file => file.File)
        .Select(data => new File
        {
            FileName = data.FirstOrDefault().File.File1,
            TotalTags = tagCount.Where(p => p.FileName.Equals(data.FirstOrDefault().File.File1)).Sum(x => x.Occurrences).ToString(),
                UnprocessedTags = unprocessedTags.Where(p => p.File.File1.Equals(data.FirstOrDefault().File.File1)).DefaultIfEmpty().Count().ToString(),
        })
        .OrderBy(fileName => fileName.FileName);

    return View(result);                    
}
```

Above piece of code gets executed super fast and I guess it is because it just generates the query itself. But at the time it goes to the view and tries to iterate to the results, it takes ages until it reach the foreach loop.

```
@model IQueryable<File>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "File";
}

<h4>Number of files: <strong> @Model.Count() </strong></h4>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @RenderItem(item);
}
```

Any idea on how I could optimize it? At the end, my query returns around 100 File objects. But the initialization of each property within the object is killing the system...

Thanks!

Comment: What I can see is that the operations that are killing my query are the two operations that are filling in TotalTags and UnprocessedTags from File object

Comment: Maybe try execute some of queries before your action method start to build result object. For example `tagCount = <query here>.Select(..).ToList()`. I think it take that much time because every sub-query is executed for each file in `listOfFiles`

Comment: Thanks for replying, your suggestion made things faster but I ended up on writing the whole query on SQL and create some views that then I referenced in my web app. That made the trick and execution is much much faster! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Sql Profiler to see what SQL commands are actually being executed. I would suspect you may be seeing multiple queries for each result returned (Ie this could be issuing over 200 SQL command for your 100 results).

You might find it faster if you retrieve TotalTags and UnprocessedTags separately and then combine them in memory.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! As I said above, I ended up on putting all the sql code on a proper sql query and created a view that I referenced in my controller. That made things much faster now. Thanks1